# Google Cloud SQL export failing with error "Could not complete the operation"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have a google storage bucket to which I want to export my google cloud sql database. I go to the `Export` tab, select a location on my bucket, give a filename, and choose the database I want to export. But I'm always greeted with **Could not complete the operation**.

It has been happening to me for the last 2 days. This flow had worked a couple of weeks ago, and I haven't tweaked around with the settings since then.

Is there a way I can get a more descriptive response, so I can identify the error? Also, how do I export my cloud sql db until then? Do I connect with the `psql` client and figure out a way from there?